# How to use Web Components with nodejs

Tags: node.js, ejs, server-side-rendering, web-component

I need to create custom element and use it in ejs:

**custom component**

```
class ErrorPopup extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.innerHTML = `
      <h1 style="color: blueviolet;">Hello</h1>  
    `
  }
}

customElements.define('error-pop-up' , ErrorPopup);
```

**ejs file**

```
<%- include('../partials/head.ejs') %>
<script type="text/html" src="../../webComponents/errorPopup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<%- include('../partials/navigation.ejs') %>
<main>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100 p-3">
        <% if (user) { %>
            <h1>Hi, there and welcome! I am <%= user.name + " " + user.lastname %>!</h1>
        <% } else { %>
            <h1><a href="/auth/signin">Sign In</a></h1>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</main>
<error-pop-up></error-pop-up>
<%- include('../partials/end.ejs') %>
```

I can see it un the DOM but no ***h1*** there:
[image]

I know that it might be done using Server Side Rendering and attaching shadow root but have no idea how to do that. Also it may be needed to do some logic in routes. Thank you for help in advance